# Callback listener after item write

Tags: spring-batch

Does Spring Batch have a callback listener after each record / item?
It is available after a "step", chunk, job etc... would seem to make sense to have a callback listener after each item write.
For some reason I never really found a way to do it after each write; this leads me to use the processor for this purpose, and handle error states in the skip listener.

I don't feel it's right, a callback after each item write seems to make sense.
How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such callback because the chunk-oriented processing model is designed to write items in bulk (all or nothing). This is typically and obviously faster than writing items one by one in separate transactions.

If you really need a listener after each item write, you can set the chunk-size to 1 and use the regular `ItemWriteListener`. Otherwise, you can do it manually in a custom item writer implementation.

Comment: I see... we want to update state per record, but that doesn't need to be after each individual item necessarily (can be done per chunk). But if we want to update error state for failed items (skipListener processor / itemWriter) without failing the entire chunk, can we do this at the end of each chunk also? I prefer indeed not to put chunk-size to 1 because it defeats all the other benefits.